# How to estimate the upper bound of $\sum_{j\ge k} \exp(-c 2^{jc'})\le ?$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to estimate the upper bound of
$$\sum_{j\ge k} \exp(-c 2^{jc'})\le ?$$
where $c, c'$ are constans.

Can we get the LHS is less than something like $\exp(-c 2^{kc'})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align} \sum_{j \ge k} \exp(-c 2^{j c'}) &= 
\sum_{k \le j \le k+1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{j c'}) + 
\sum_{j \ge 1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{k c'}2^{j c'}) 
\\ &\le
\sum_{k \le j \le k+1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{j c'}) + 
\sum_{j \ge 1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{k c'}2^{j c'}) 
\\ &\le
\frac1{c'} \exp(-c 2^{j c'}) + 
\sum_{j > 1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{k c'}2^{j c'}) 
\end{align}
Now use $2^{j c'} \ge j c'$.  Then
\begin{align} 
\sum_{j \ge 1/c'} \exp(-c 2^{k c'}2^{j c'})
&\le \sum_{j \ge 1/c'} [\exp(-c 2^{k c'})]^{jc'} 
\\&\le \frac{\exp(-c 2^{k c'})}{1-\exp(-c 2^{k c'})^{c'}}
\\&= \frac{\exp(-c 2^{k c'})}{1-\exp(-c 2^{ c'})^{c'}}
\end{align}

So there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$ \sum_{j \ge k} \exp(-c 2^{j c'}) \le C \exp(-c 2^{k c'}) $$

There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing.  The idea is to be very careless with the bounds, and reduce to geometric series.

Comment: So the upper bound is $1/(1-\exp(c2^{kc'}))^c$?

Comment: You want to use the style of the argument rather than the exact details.  Perhaps treat the first term separately.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused about that. Can we get an upper bound like $\exp(-c2^{kc'})$?

Comment: OK, how is this?

Comment: Thank you very much!